# Problems setting table headers to expand horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-table

[Invoice Picture](https://flic.kr/p/S9SsN7)

Hello Guys,

I just started learning HTML and CSS and decided to start on my first learning project. I am trying to re-create an invoice template exactly like the one on the attached picture. I am having issues aligning the table headers that say "Ship Method, Orde Date..." to expand across like on the picture. I have tried adjusting the width within the th tag and setting a pixel value, but I am stuck.

Thanks for your help, guys!

Here is what I have coded so far:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"> 
 <style>
   body {
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         margin: 0;
         body: 0;
        }

   .shipto {

        color: #fff;
        white-space: pre;
        background:#000;
        width: 40px;
        height: 225px; 
        position: relative; 
        left: 400px;
        bottom: 30px; 
           }

   .top-box {
        color: #fff;
        table-layout: fixed;
          }

    th {
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
       }


 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2926/32085237484_4b8c92a6b2_z.jpg" width="300" height="44" alt="Adidas Logo">
 <div class="shipto">
 <h4>
     S
     h
     i
     p

     T
     o
   </h4>
  <div class="top-box">
   <table border="1" summary="order information" bgcolor="black" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>
     <th>SHIP METHOD</th>
     <th>ORDER DATE</th>
     <th>ORDER NO.</th>
     <th>DELIVERY NO.</th>
     <th>PAYMENT TYPE</th>

    </tr>
 </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use , `height:0/auto`, also `min-height` and the `:empty` pseudo to hide some cells.

rowspan and colspan can be also very usefull

The tag `caption` can also be used

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height:80vh;
  margin:auto;
}
tr >*{
height:0;
}
tr:first-child,
tr:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

tr:last-child >*{
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

th,
td {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 0.2em 1em 0.5em;
}

th:empty {
  display: none;
}
caption {
caption-side:left;
writing-mode:vertical-lr;
text-align:center;
min-height:80vh;
font-size:2em;
background:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<table>
<caption>Shipto</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Ship Method</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
    <th>Order No.</th>
    <th>Delivery No.</th>
    <th>Payment Type</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">UPS 2 Days Res. UPSZ</td>
    <td>06/27/2015</td>
    <td>A002324434a</td>
    <td>2203552102</td>
    <td>VISA9738</td>
    <td>Unit Pr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line #</td>
    <td>ITEM / UPC</td>
    <td colspan="4">Desciption</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AQ432_11</td>
    <td colspan="4">YEEZY BOOST 350 mULTI</td>
    <td>$ 2222.22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Ship Method</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
    <th>Order No.</th>
    <th>Delivery No.</th>
    <th>Payment Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">UPS 2 Days Res. UPSZ</td>
    <td>06/27/2015</td>
    <td>A002324434a</td>
    <td>2203552102</td>
    <td>VISA9738</td>
    <td>Unit ..</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line #</td>
    <td>ITEM / UPC</td>
    <td colspan="4">Desciption</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AQ432_11</td>
    <td colspan="4">YEEZY BOOST 350 mULTI</td>
    <td>$ 2...</td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
tr:first-child, tr:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
tr:last-child {
 height: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Ship Method</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
    <th>Order No.</th>
    <th>Delivery No.</th>
    <th>Payment Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">UPS 2 Days Res. UPSZ</td>
    <td>06/27/2015</td>
    <td>A002324434a</td>
    <td>2203552102</td>
    <td>VISA9738</td>
    <td>Unit ..</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line #</td>
    <td>ITEM / UPC</td>
    <td colspan="4">Desciption</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>AQ432_11</td>
    <td colspan="4">YEEZY BOOST 350 mULTI</td>
    <td>$ 2...</td>
  </tr>
    
  
  
</table>
```